# Loop is infinitly looping or IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index =4, Size =2

Tags: java, android, arraylist

in this function when I use the **For..Loop** it is **looping infinitly** and when I use the **While..Loop**  I got the Error: **IndexOutOfBoundsException**. What Iam trying to do is to copy the elements from the **imageInfosArrayList** that are in a certain range, into **restrictedAreaArrayList** and here is the code:

```
 @Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    //Toast.makeText(this,"Location changed!! wait for coordiates update",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    mLocation=location;


    latitudeMe=mLocation.getLatitude();
    longitudeMe=mLocation.getLongitude();
    Log.i(TAG,String.valueOf(latitudeMe+","+longitudeMe));

    getMyLocations(latitudeMe,longitudeMe);
    //getLocations("München Flughafen");
    Log.i(TAG,"Ziel coordinates "+String.valueOf(latitudeZiel+","+latitudeZiel));
   // for (int i = 0; i < imageInfosArrayList.size(); i++) {

    int i=0;
    while(i<imageInfosArrayList.size()){
        Log.e(TAG,imageInfosArrayList.toString());
        LatLng hier = getLocations(imageInfosArrayList.get(i).getPlace());
        if (hier != null) {
            Log.i(TAG, imageInfosArrayList.get(i).getPlace());

            distanceGeo = distance(hier.latitude, hier.longitude);
            ImageInfos imageInfos= new ImageInfos(mContext);



            if (distanceGeo <= Float.valueOf(distance[0])) {
                imageInfos= imageInfosArrayList.get(i);

                restrictedAreaArrayList.add(i,imageInfos);
                Log.e(TAG, "restrictedarea filling..." + restrictedAreaArrayList.size());
                i++;
            }
        } else {
            Log.i(TAG, "Can't locate this adress..." + imageInfosArrayList.get(i).getPlace());
            i++;
        }
    }

}
```

Here is the Logcat:

```
com.historyimages E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                    Process: bayram.com.historyimages, PID: 9792
                                                                    java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 4, Size: 2
                                                                        at java.util.ArrayList.add(ArrayList.java:457)
                                                                        at bayram.com.historyimages.Umgebung.UmgebungFragment.onLocationChanged(UmgebungFragment.java:394)
                                                                        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzasg$zzb$1.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzasg$zzb$1.zzs(Unknown Source)
                                                                        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzabh.zzb(Unknown Source)
                                                                        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzabh$zza.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6524)
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:941)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:831)
```

Comment: Try moving the `i++` outside the if/else block

Comment: add the error logs or add details about the line on which error occured

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting `IndexOutOfBoundsException` on `restrictedAreaArrayList`,
You are adding `imageInfos` to 
`restrictedAreaArrayList`

with

`restrictedAreaArrayList.add(i,imageInfos);`

ith index may not exist in `restrictedAreaArrayList` you can just add it

`restrictedAreaArrayList.add(imageInfos)`

Or if you want to preserve the order then make restrictedAreaArrayList's size equal to `imageInfosArrayList`
you can do that by creating it with

`restrictedAreaArrayList = new ArrayList<ImageInfos>(imageInfosArrayList.size());`

Or

you can call

`restrictedAreaArrayList.ensureCapacity(imageInfosArrayList.size())`

to make sure it has same capacity as `imageInfosArrayList`

Answer (score 0):

Well, we don't have the code for your for loop example, but I suspect it contains a similar mistake was in the while loop.

Your loop, simplified looks like this:

```
int i = 0;
while (i < size_of_x) {
    y = getlocations(h.get(i));
    if (y != null) {
        do_something()
        i++;
    }
    else {
        i++;
    }
}
```

Let us imagine then that the h only has 2 elements, so get(0) and get(1) will work but get(2) will fail. Your loop runs with the following behavior:

1. i = 0; getlocations(h.get(0)) returns NULL; i = 1.
2. i = 1; getLocations(h.get(1)) returns NULL; i = 2.
3. i = 2; getLocations(h.get(2)) fails because the index is out of bounds, so you get an IndexOutOfBoundsException.

I'm guessing your for loop version had more differences than implied with the code you posted, but likely ran "infinitely" because your terminating condition wasn't satisfied due to something like the getlocations() call that doesn't succeed.

You need to rethink what you're doing in the loop, especially if you're making function calls that can fail. You should also practice the exercise I described above, walking through your code, and checking whether behavior in the loop matches what you expect or wanted.

Comment: I already did, but the first 2 elements aren't NUll and 3 elements should be there at least that i am sure of it.

Comment: @Bayram The first 2 elements of what? There are several lists in your code and multiple ways to generate the exception. How are you "sure" of it? Did you actually check?

Comment: yes i did, i tried something els, instead of filling a new Arraylist i used remove(i), so from 6 i got 4. but now the problem is when i try to pass the imageinfosarraylist to the adapter of myrecyclerview i got Inconsistensy detected. 
Here are the elements of my infoarraylist:
[bayram.com.historyimages.DataBase.ImageInfos@e4dcea, bayram.com.historyimages.DataBase.ImageInfos@3bd8bdb, bayram.com.historyimages.DataBase.ImageInfos@eb37678, bayram.com.historyimages.DataBase.ImageInfos@9523151]